# "colon" notation in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to `Ruby`, and trying to read/understand some `rb` files. I've come across this line. Could anyone explain what it is doing (and the gramatical meaning behind it, too)?

```
@account = current_user.accounts.find(params[:id])
```

- **1:** what is `current_user`? I grepped the entire file, but didn't see where it was declared. (Well, I know variables don't need to be declared in Ruby, but it is  not referred to with an @ sign, so this might not be a variable?)
  Where should I expect to find `current_user`? (ie., in `app/model`, `app/view`, etc?)
- **2:** What is the meaning of `:id`?
  `params` looks like an array, so I guess `:id` somehow means the index, but why is there the `colon` before `id`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is `current_user`?

It's often hard to tell the difference between a local variable and a method being called.  This is because the `()` is optional, and often omitted.  In this case, `current_user` is a method, declared in a mixin or superclass somewhere, which is why it's not in this file.  Think of `current_user.accounts` as `current_user().accounts`, which should illustrate what's going on there.

> Where should I expect to find `current_user`?

Most likely, it provided in a plugin or gem that handles authentication for your project.  It's hard to advise more than that without knowing more about your project.

> What is the meaning of `:id`? `params`

It's pulling a value from a hash, by it's key.  In irb, try this:

```
params = { :id => 123 }
puts params[:id] # => prints 123
```

So params is a hash (some languages call this datatype an associative array, or a dictionary). It's a way to store a set of key/value pairs.  The `somehash[somekey]` notation returns the value for `somekey` in `somehash`.

`:id` itself is a symbol.  It's sort of like a string that never changes. Do some research on ruby symbols to learn more on that.

And in rails, `params` is a special hash. Values passed form the request show up in this hash. So the route `/books/:id` would active when you load `/books/123`, which would set `params[:id]` to `123` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Current user is likely provided by a gem.  Example of a gem would be [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).
2. "params" is a hash of the parameters passed as the query string on the URI.  So, ":id" would reference the value of the id parameter.

Example:

www.domain.com?id=abc would yield params[:id] as "abc".